# Seeing multiple records where one record per invoice is expected in an aggregate - SQL Server

Tags: sql, aggregate

I'm a CTO for a small manufacturing firm, obviously doing some very hands on stuff and am grateful to experts out there providing their time to people less experienced.

I'm trying to construct a query for SQL Server to aggregate time for each machine in a manufacturing process.

The results I get look something like:

```
InvoiceID Min DateIn      MachineName  MachineID
17993     12  2012-09-28  Beam Saw     1
17993     26  2012-09-28  Beam Saw     1
17993     17  2012-10-02  Edge Banding 3
17993     21  2012-10-02  Skipper      4
17993     23  2012-10-03  Shipping     5
```

etc for next invoice.

My code:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceID
    ,SUM(DATEPART(Minute,(wf.DateTimeOut - wf.DateTimeIn))) AS [Min]
    ,CAST(wf.DateTimeIn AS DATE) AS [DateIn]
    ,m.MachineName
    ,wf.MachineID
FROM Workflow wf 
    JOIN
        InvoicesPerJobPeriod ipjp
        ON
        ipjp.Workflowid = wf.ID
    JOIN Machines m
        ON 
        m.MachineID = wf.MachineID
    JOIN
        Invoices i
        ON ipjp.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
WHERE (i.InActive = '0') 
GROUP BY i.InvoiceID, m.MachineName, wf.MachineID, wf.DateTimeIn
ORDER BY i.InvoiceID, wf.MachineID
```

I don't understand why the grouping shows multiple records for the Beam Saw. Ideally, there should be one record per machine, per invoice. The Datetimein is usually going to be the same day, but I need to display it, just in case a manufacturing step spans days. In that case I would reasonable to have multiple records for a machine.

Thank you so much for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

Cliff

Comment: Try it without the cast on DateTimeIn. I'm guessing there are two different formats being stored in the database. If you are getting two records it is because of the fields in your GROUP BY. If you cast in your GROUP BY you will take care of that though it could be a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wf.DateTimeIn` is different at all (in either the date or the time components) for two different Beam Saw records, they will generate separate lines in the `GROUP BY` clause, even though your non-aggregated usage in the `SELECT` statement is only referring to the date portion.

If what you want is to group by the date portion of `DateTimeIn` only, you should write something like this:

```
GROUP BY i.InvoiceID, m.MachineName, wf.MachineID, CAST(wf.DateTimeIn AS DATE)
```

This will ensure that any number of Beam Saw records that otherwise match and are entered on the same date will be grouped together into a single row.

However, this may change the semantics of your aggregate statement, so you'll need to verify the query works as you desire after you make this change.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I'm able to keep the CAST in the field listing with the second answer, and the CAST in the GROUP BY works.